# Is it possible to test my application with two iPads in XCode?

Tags: xcode, swift, testing

Let's say I'm writing a chat application, is it possible to connect two of my iPads to my Mac and somehow be used in testing to send each other data? (Instead of using the simulator?)

Comment: Yeah, you'd just deploy the app on both iPads and communicate as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
First you need connect both ipad to mac then run on each ipad(any ios device)   one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can connect multiple iPads (or any iOS device) to your mac and then run on each device as you desire.